# Armature - Blind Angles, Dead Areas, Pole Control

Tags: armature

I want to make a simple robot arm with a light attached. With "Forward Kinematik" everything works just fine.

[image]

Version A:

When I add bones and Inverse Kinematik there are "dead areas" the robot arm cant reach. Also the knee flips suddenly after the IK target has moved through the "dead area".
[image]
[image]

Version B:

To avoid the knee flipping I tried using a "Pole Target", but then the whole armature "rolls", even though I locked rotation for every axis not required to rotate. I did not make pictures of that, because I hope for a solution with Version A

I made a video of the dead area, it has a strange shape.

[Example Video](https://youtu.be/Y_X6ZblM4-M)